# CSS Affect Only One Character Site-Wide

Tags: css, wordpress, character

I am trying to make one character have a certain style across my site (Wordpress). I need some code like:

```
"T" {
   color: red;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to style the first letter of a paragraph of text specially? If so, see my answer below about using `:first-letter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"T"` isn't a valid CSS selector, so your example won't work. But you can use the [`:first-letter` pseudo-selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-letter) to style the first letter of a paragraph differently:

```
p:first-letter { 
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Is there a last-letter one too?

Comment: Yeah kinda careless in my linking. Updated to link to the CSS spec instead

Comment: @ErwaySoftware I don't see a builtin `:last-letter` selector available, but this page may be useful since it links to a JavaScript library that may add that feature: http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked. Accepting this suggests that the intended question was completely different.

Comment: My answer first stated that what the question was asking is not possible, and then offered an alternative suggestion. It seems to me that a valid answer is one that solves the questioner's problem, possibly by offering an alternate solution they were unaware of, and that helps everyone learn something (and isn't that why we're here?)

Answer (score 4):

Nope, there's no way of doing this with CSS alone.

An alternative is to wrap all text outputted with `span` tags with a class like `<span class="T">T</span>` and define the class in CSS normally.

```
.T {
    color: red;
}
```